# socket.recv bufsize too large and server loop not exiting after file sent

Tags: python, sockets

I am sending a file over to a server, and I am using `s.send(text)` and `s.recv(4096)` on the server to get the file.

The problem is that the file size varies, and when I send over a small file of only a few lines of text, if I print what I receive on the server side, I get the few lines of text, plus hundreds of lines of blank space.

I may sometimes send larger files, so I want to keep bufsize at 4096, but how do I get rid of the blank space that is printed? In this case, I only want to receive the few lines of text.

As well, the server loop is not exiting, even though I am using s.close() on both ends of the script (server and client).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file

Comment: protocol (n) a set of rules governing the format of messages that are exchanged between computers

Comment: recv() retuns a value.  You should look up what it is and why it matters.